# SQL Server 2008 grand total using COMPUTE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

A simple table query I have shows this:

```
salesAreaId areaDescription Total
----------- --------------- -----------
N1          North           5
SE8         Southeast       3
SW7         Southwest       2
NE6         Northeast       2
NW5         Northwest       1
S3          South           1
W4          West            1
E2          East            1

(8 row(s) affected)
```

Here is my code

```
SELECT st.salesAreaId, areaDescription,  
    COUNT(*) as Total
FROM store as st, salesArea as sa
WHERE st.salesAreaId = sa.salesAreaId
GROUP BY st.salesAreaId, areaDescription
ORDER BY 3 DESC
GO
```

My question is how to add a Grand Total row below the total column using COMPUTE, I was taught to use COMPUTE after ORDER BY

I do not want to use ROLLUP, do I need some kind of inside SELECT to use Total separately. 
Every example I read says to type the column name next to SUM like this

Any suggestions?

Comment: what's the reason rejecting ROLLUP?

Comment: @Nico I can't remember now, :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT st.salesAreaId, areaDescription,  
COUNT(*) as Total
FROM store as st, salesArea as sa
WHERE st.salesAreaId = sa.salesAreaId
GROUP BY st.salesAreaId, areaDescription
--order by would go here if needed - ordering by a constant won't have any effect though, so I've removed it from the statment
compute sum(count(*))
```

You can replace sum with any aggregate function.
I've used count(*) as the thing you're doing a grant total on as you used that for your sub totals - but you can replace that with a column name / whatever's required.

ps. looking at your data it seems you may be after sub totals per area?  If so, try this:

```
SELECT st.salesAreaId
, areaDescription
, COUNT(*) as Total
FROM store as st
inner join salesArea as sa
on st.salesAreaId = sa.salesAreaId
GROUP BY st.salesAreaId, areaDescription
ORDER BY st.salesAreaId, areaDescription
COMPUTE sum(count(*)) BY areaDescription
```

Comment: Yes sir, that displays my sum at the bottom. Is there anyway to change the sum label to a different label when displayed?

Comment: I couldn't find an option (even if you have two aggregates with the same name you get the same column name, which was surprising).  However in researching this I found that Compute is deprecated in SQL 2012: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/04/02/sql-server-use-roll-up-clause-instead-of-compute-by/.  Looking into the difference it seems the reason is to allow your grand total to be in the same column as your total.  Presumably that's part of the reason Compute By's being deprecated?